# What am I doing wrong while getting URL

Tags: php, html, http-host

I want to place links on my page.

I use

```
echo "<a href=\"".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/projecten/project.php?project=1";
```

I want to go to `mydomain.nl/project/project.ph?project=1`
but instead of that link I get `http://mydomain.nl/projecten/mydomain/projecten/project.php?project=1`

I thought that

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

would give me `http://mydomain.nl`, why isn't it doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start your link with `http://`, `https://` or [`//`](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/). [`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) only contains the host, not the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify protocol
that is http://

```
echo '<a href="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'"/projecten/project.php?project=1';
```

or 
for secure link use

```
echo '<a href="https://'.$_SERVER['HTTPS_HOST'].'"/projecten/project.php?project=1';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easy see what configuration is used by this scriplet

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

i thougt what you want is to use $_SERVER[**"SERVER_NAME"**]